# If C++ already needs to abide by C++ standards to compile, what's the point of the g++ -pedantic flag?

Tags: c++, g++

I don't understand the interest of the g++ `-pedantic` flag.

Code isn't supposed to abide by the C++ standards to compile by default ?

If I add this flag or if I don't add it, the compiler should logically issue the same warnings right ?

Comment: G++ is not unique in defaulting to turning on extensions that are not actually part of the standard. Sometimes it causes confusion: there's a whole lot of questions that end up boiling down to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) because G++ turns on variable-length arrays by default. But it's nevertheless the case.

Comment: Two words: Backwards compatibility.  More words: There were C++ compilers before C++ was standardized so there are C++ code bases that have pre-standard code, and a lot of those were allowed to keep compiling.

Comment: Two more words: Commercial Expediency. If I used a compiler that ate my cat every time I wrote an undefined statement like `unsigned n = -1e1;` I'd switch to another vendor.

Answer (score 5):

> If I add this flag or if I don't add it, the compiler should logically issue the same warnings right ?

No, compilers typically default to a variation of C++ with extensions and minor differences relative to the standard. For example GCC by default supports variable-length arrays. According to the standard these are ill-formed and so GCC should produce a diagnostic for them. `-pedantic` does that.

To get closest to standard conformance you need `-std=c++XX -pedantic-errors` on GCC with `XX` replaced by the standard version. `-pedantic-errors` can also be `-pedantic`. Warnings for ill-formed code are sufficient for standard-conformance.

100% conformance isn't possible anyway. The language specification is too complex and not all details are well-specified. In some cases compilers also intentionally deviate from the specification even in stricter conformance mode because it makes more sense in practice to consider the specified behavior a defect in the standard, even if it hasn't been resolved as such yet.

> If C++ already needs to abide by C++ standards to compile [...]

The question doesn't really make sense. Where would the imperative that code needs to abide by the standard come from in a non-circular way? Of course a compiler can also support code that isn't well-formed according to the standard. There is no higher authority requiring that a "C++ compiler" must conform to the ISO C++ standard.

And even if the compiler intents that to be the case: In some cases the standard says that a conforming compiler should issue some diagnostic to be conforming, but it never requires a compiler not to support any given code as valid.

Answer (score 1):

The point of pedantic is explained in the documentation:

> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++.

There are code constructs, in which the warning is *not* demanded by ISO C++ and the behavior of a program is undefined according to ISO C++. But undefined behavior means that the standard does not place *any requirements* on the behavior of the program. So the compiler *can* come up with its own behavior. Such behavior *is* standard conforming, "abides" by C++ standard, but still is something that is not inside C++ standard. `-pedantic` is to warn on programs that use such extensions to the standard.

`-pedantic` is for https://eel.is/c++draft/intro#compliance.general-8 :

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program.
> Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this document.
> Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.